# How to make a dll as a Microservice and make it reside outside the system

Tags: c#, .net, dll, microservices

My requirement is simple.

We have a system with so many components interacting with each other. All the components are built as DLLs and interact via object.

So lets say I have a component XXX. Now I want to remove the component XXX outside the system and want the user to install the component XXX only when he needs.

I want to make XXX as an "Extensible" and a "Pluggable" component and develop and build it independently and whenever the user needs the functionality that is provided by the XXX dll, he will install XXX dll as a standalone component.

Also, XXX dll interacts with other components in the system,say YYY, using objects. Components are binded by objects.

If i want to make XXX dll as a outside component, how does the communication XXX and YYY component happen now? I was thinking components can communicate over a Web Service interface.

Any leads or pointers on how I can proceed with this idea? I am searching for it all regarding Micro-services and others but I am not able to come up with a good feasible approach.

Comment: Lets start with the basics... are we talking about plain old DLL files or about .Net Assemblies that (for some reason) also have the .dll file extension?

Comment: These components are .NET assemblies built for specific flavors like Windows XP, Windows CE and Windows CE_ARM

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use some bus implementation instead of plain web service call. For example you might use NServiceBus for such purposes. This will make component communication more transparent and robust (you will get load balancing, fallback mechanisms and lot more out of the box). Or you could use some queue implementation (if you won't purchase NServiceBus). RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ or anything else like that would be a good choise (base on your requirements of course). This approach will give you a lot of advantages as well.